# off someone's feet?

Tags: prepositions

What does "off" mean in "off someone's feet" in the following?

> The doctor told me to stay **off** my feet for a few days.
>
> They were blown **off** their feet by the force of the explosion.
>
> Before Christmas, most salespeople are rushed **off** their feet.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It means the opposite of  **on** their feet.

Answer (score 1):

All three cited contexts have significantly different meanings - which is to say that ***off one's feet*** doesn't actually have a single precise meaning. Context is everything...

> 1: *The doctor told me to stay off my feet for a few days.*
>   The doctor is advising the patient to *take it easy, rest up, spend more time sitting down*.
>
> 2: *They were blown off their feet by the force of the explosion.*
>    The explosive blast was so powerful that people nearby were *propelled off the ground* briefly (their feet actually lost contact with the ground for some amount of time).
>
> 3: *Before Christmas, most salespeople are rushed off their feet.*
>    The salespeople were so busy serving customers that they wouldn't have had time to sit and rest.

But all the above are perfectly common idiomatic usages (where the *specific* sense is strongly associated with the preceding verb - ***stay, blown, rushed***). One more relatively common one that comes to mind is...

> 4: *She survived by dreaming about being picked by a wealthy man who would [sweep her off her feet](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sweep%20her%20off%20her%20feet%22) and rescue her from her miserable life.*
>   She hopes to meet a man who will ***really captivate / impress her***.